# how to get div value from repeater in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a code like

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repBalanceSheet" runat="server">
 <HeaderTemplate>
 <div class="left">
 <div class="columns">
 <div class="column">
 <div class="left-cells r1 heading">Fiscal year ends in December</div>
 <div class="left-cells r2 bg heading">USD in Million except per share data</div>
 <div class="left-cells r3 l3 heading level1">Assets</div>
 <div class="left-cells r4 l4 heading level2">Current assets</div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </HeaderTemplate>
 <ItemTemplate>
 <div class="<%# "column c" + Container.ItemIndex.ToString() %>">
 <div class="<%# "heading r1 second1 c" + Container.ItemIndex.ToString() %>">
 <%# FormatDate(Eval("ReportDate"))  %></div>
 <div class="<%# "bg r2 c" + Container.ItemIndex.ToString() %>"></div>
 <div class="<%# "right-cells r3 c" + Container.ItemIndex.ToString() %>"></div>
 <div class="<%# "right-cells r4 c" + Container.ItemIndex.ToString() %>"></div>
 </div>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

now I want to access the repeater into Jquery can anyone please tell how to get the values of repeate in Jquery.

Comment: you want to get its html ?

Comment: no I want the value of  <%# FormatDate(Eval("ReportDate"))  %></div> tag using jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
$('.heading.r1.second1.c').text();
```

#### Note:

> Form elements can have values but div can contain text and forms, so if this is the case then you can use ".val()" to get the values.